# Allowing a null parameter as an argument in a SQL Select

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a foreign key to itself to keep track of ParentID. This is used to make a treelike hierarchy in the database. I'm trying to create a function that will find all rows that have a particular ParentID. However, if a record is a Root record it's parent is NULL. Therefore if I want to find all root tables I need to be able to enter NULL as an option as well. What I have so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM X.Y 
    WHERE 
        CASE 
            WHEN @ParentID IS NULL THEN ParentID IS NULL 
            WHEN @ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN ParentID = @ParentID 
        END
```

I think I'm on the right track, but haven't quite figured it out. It is saying `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'` indicating the `IS` in `THEN ParentID IS NULL`.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM X.Y 
WHERE (@ParentID IS NULL AND ParentID IS NULL )
   OR (ParentID = @ParentID )
```

About the first clause in my WHERE statement:  any comparison to a NULL or a field whose value is NULL will always return false.  Even `WHERE NULL = NULL` will evaluate as false.

So if you want to say, "Do this if both my variable and the field itself are null" you need to use something like `WHERE (@ParentID IS NULL AND ParentID IS NULL )`.

Some people like to do something like this:

```
WHERE (ISNULL(@ParentID,0) = ISNULL(ParentID,0)
```

It's tidy, but it doesn't allow the query engine to take advantages of the indexes that you might have on your table. It's considered a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the second WHEN to an ELSE or simply using an or like this

```
SELECT * FROM X.Y 
WHERE ParentID IS NULL OR ParentID = @ParentID
```

Comment: I'll check the ELSE. The OR option won't work because if they put in a non-null value for @ParentID it would return all the correct records as well as all the records where ParentID is NULL. Unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Replacing the WHEN with an ELSE has not removed the syntax error at IS.